# Получение пути к скрипту для обращения к лежащим рядом файлам

Tags: linux, macos, консоль, scss, terminal

Создал файл .sh для терминала на macOS для того чтобы не включать SCSS каждый раз вручную.

Код такой

```
cd assets
cd css
sass --watch input.scss:style.css
```

Сам файл терминала находится в папке с такой структурой:

```
Folder/assets/css
```

Файлы для преобразования на месте, но скрипт почему то выдает что такая папка отсутствует.

**P.S. При запуске напрямую из терминала все работает.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
realpath() {
local p=$1
if [ "${p%${p#?}}" != "/" ]; then
p="$(pwd)/$p"
fi
echo "$p"
}
echo $(dirname $(realpath $0))
```

Comment: смысл в том, что в ОС есть понятие текущего каталога, все команды работают относительно него. Или меняйте каталог перед тем, как запустить скрипт или в самом скрипте пишите код по определению нужного каталога исходя из потребностей вашего проекта. например по месту нахождения текущего запущенного скрипта http://andrew.bogdanovs.com/post/bash_tricks_script_dir.html  Причем первый подход кажется правильным, потому что если у вас на диске две разных проекта и в каждом лежит такой скрипт то при запуске скрипта просто по имени как вы поймете какой из них вы запустили ?

Comment: А выдача команды pwd при запуске скрипта из окошка и из терминала не отличается ?

Comment: @Mike получилось. Скрипт запускался в папке предшествующей Work которая является корнем

Comment: @Mike теперь тогда встаёт вопрос: как тогда сделать так чтобы скрипт запускался из папки в которой находится а не из корневой?

Comment: Если он запускается из корневой то я не понимаю почему dirname дает просто точку, он должен дать Folder. А вообще гугл сказал это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572030/bash-script-absolute-path-with-osx

Comment: @Mike я писал dirname path. Может поэтому?

Comment: почему dirname path, если нужен `dirname $0`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70592/discussion-on-question-by-brachkoff-----sh).

Comment: @Mike, ответы - в ответы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у скрипта, интерпретируемого posix-совместимой «оболочкой», имеется переменная `$0`, содержащая путь к этому скрипту.

проблема в том, что если он был запущен с указанием *относительного* пути, то именно этот относительный путь и попадёт в эту переменную.

например, при запуске `./скрипт` (или `sh ./скрипт`) в переменной будет записано именно `./скрипт`.

да, конечно, программой [*pwd*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html) можно получить абсолютный путь к каталогу, в котором была выполнена эта команда, и, добавив к пути, возвращаемому программой *pwd*, относительного пути, взятого из переменной `$0`, можно получить полный путь к скрипту.

например, если текущим каталогом при описанном выше запуске был `/каталог`, то полный путь получаем соединением того, что вернёт программа *pwd* (`/каталог`), добавлением `/` в конце, и содержимым переменной `$0` (`./скрипт`), резульат: `/каталог/./скрипт`. всё в порядке.

но это не сработает, если при вызове скрипта был указан *абсолютный* путь типа `/какой/то/путь/скрипт`. он попадёт в переменную `$0`, и приставив к нему слева текущий каталог, мы получим неправильный результат: `/каталог//какой/то/путь/скрипт`.

также абсолютный путь попадёт в переменную `$0`, если каталог, в котором лежит скрипт, присутствует в переменной окружения `$PATH`, а скрипт был запущен просто указанием имени, без какого-либо пути (запустили `скрипт`, в `$0` получили полный путь, например, `/usr/bin/скрипт`).

---

хорошо, если у вас операционная система *gnu*, ведь в ней имеется программа *realpath*, с помощью которой легко можно получить абсолютный путь в обоих ситуациях: `realpath "$0"` вернёт именно то, что нам требуется.

в других posix-совместимых операционных системах алгоритм получения пути такой:

- если в переменной `$0` находится абсолютный путь (т.е., он начинается с `/`), то ничего слева добавлять не нужно.
- иначе надо добавить слева то, что вернёт программа `pwd`.

вот простенькая реализация функции *realpath*, эмулирующей поведение программы *gnu/realpath*:

```
realpath() {
  local p=$1
  if [ "${p%${p#?}}" != "/" ]; then
    p="$(pwd)/$p"
  fi
  echo "$p"
}
# использование:
realpath "$0"
```

ну а получив абсолютный путь к скрипту, можно уже с помощью программы [*dirname*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) получить каталог, в котором находится скрипт, а затем добавить к нему нужные элементы (`../каталог` и т.п.)

Comment: У меня dirname $0 выдает путь до папки folder где лежит скрипт. Однако при запуске он все равно не видет папки лежащие в folder.

Comment: вам надо передавать программе *dirname* не содержимое переменной `$0`, а то, что возвращает предложенная мной функция `realpath`: `echo $(dirname $(realpath $0))`

Comment: я посмотрел, вообщем такая картина - dirname $0 показывает папку в которой лежит скрипт, realpath показывает путь до скрипта, а ls почему то показывает содержимое корневой директории.

Comment: то что вы описали в своем коментарии вообще не исполняется

Comment: сначала должно идти описание функции, затем — её использование. не наоборот. приложите к вопросу текущее содержимое тестового скрипта, которое у вас «не работает».

Comment: комментарии не подходят для отображения форматированного текста. повторяю просьбу: приложите к вопросу текущее содержимое тестового скрипта, которое у вас «не работает».

Comment: Я изучил поведение скрипта и понял что он лежит в папке а исполняется в корне. Осталось только узнать почему.

Comment: у вас синтаксическая ошибка была. я исправил. *Осталось только узнать почему* — потому что текущий каталог — это свойство процесса, наследуемое от родительского процесса. изменить текущий каталог процесса, выполняемого оболочкой (как раз ваш случай), можно внутренней командой оболочки `cd путь`.

Comment: смысл тогда этого скрипта? на винде он лежал в любой папке с такой же структурой и работал. Тут же мне придется переделывать его под каждую (если я правильно вас понял),  и в таком случае мне проще будет каждый раз писать команду.

Comment: *сосчитав до ста и выдохнув*. командой `cd` вы можете изменить текущий каталог выполняющегося процесса. если вам нужен текущим, например, каталог, в котором находится интерпретируемый в данный момент скрипт оболочки, вы можете воспользоваться предложенной мною функцией `realpath` для получения этого пути и передачи его команде `cd`. например: `cd $(dirname $(realpath $0))`

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает